# Node JS Form with dropzone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node JS express to develop a Form where people can upload a file and metadata of that file. I am following this [tutorial](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/uploading-files-with-dropzone-js-and-express-js/), but couldn't add the form.

I am using Dropzone for uploading file, I should get the link `server+name_of_file`

Whenever I try to print the values of the form, I just get the object that hold only file without fname/lastname

```
<div id="uploader">
        <form action="/upload" class="dz"
          id="i-dz">
         <input type="text" name="fname">
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
      </form>
      </div>


app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
   console.log(res)
  //var form = new multiparty.Form();

}
```